# ValueError: could not convert string to float in plotting

Tags: python, string, plot

Hi I tried use this code for plotting. However, during running the code there are problem on converting string to float for the x, y, z, data. Here is the code

```
x = data_sss.iloc[:,0].astype(float)
y = data_sss.iloc[:,1].astype(float)
z = data_sss.iloc[:,2].astype(float)

x, y, z = np.loadtxt("try1.csv", unpack=True)
N = int(len(SSS)**.5)
z = SSS.reshape(N, N)
plt.imshow(z, extent=(np.amin(x), np.amax(x), np.amin(y), np.amax(y)), 
norm=LogNorm(), aspect = 'auto')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

and here is the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20520\3739732047.py in <module>
----> 1 x, y, z = np.loadtxt("try1.csv", unpack=True)
      2 N = int(len(SSS)**.5)
      3 z = SSS.reshape(N, N)
      4 plt.imshow(z, extent=(np.amin(x), np.amax(x), np.amin(y), n 
np.amax(y)), norm=LogNorm(), aspect = 'auto')
    5 plt.colorbar()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,134,34.5'
```

I also attached the picture of my datasets [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecxaE.png)

Comment: Try defining the `delimiter` when calling `np.loadtxt()`. So like this: `np.loadtxt("try1.csv", delimiter=',', unpack=True)`

Comment: Hi, it works, however, there is an error for another code, which is ValueError. The error is show below.

Comment: ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21664\4197195956.py in <module>
      1 x, y, z = np.loadtxt("try1.csv", delimiter=',', unpack=True)
      2 N = int(len(z)**.5)
----> 3 z = z.reshape(N, N)
      4 plt.imshow(z, extent=(np.amin(x), np.amax(x), np.amin(y), np.amax(y)), norm=LogNorm(), aspect = 'auto')
      5 plt.colorbar()

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 14640 into shape (120,120)

Comment: That seems to be another question/error entirely. It has to do with `SSS`. What is the value of `SSS`? Please add more details about it in your question. You also want to update your question to include what you've changed and what the new error code that you got is.